# Java connect Oracle with database link

Tags: java, database, oracle

I add a database link in Oracle. I can use SQL Developer to use this link name connect to other Oracle database like:

```
Select * from user@testDBLink
```

(It works)

When I use PreparedStatement to query the database will get exception, the exception is:

> ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found

I had printed the PreparedStatement SQL statement is same to:

```
Select * from user@testDBLink
```

But if I use DriverManager will success for query the database.
Any direction or idea for this question.

Comment: Are you connecting to the database as the same user through your Java code and from SQL Developer?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes I have check this.The username are same in sql developer,PreparedStatement  and DriverManager .

Comment: The error message suggests that the database link does not exist in the schema you are connected to. Is your Java session connected to the correct database? The one you created the database link in, not the one the database link is connected to.

Comment: @Rene Yes,I want use "A database" connect to "B database".I had created a database link on "A database" and use sql developer connecting to "A database".Then query the table using database link the sql like post above.  Testing the database link is correct and work.Then I write my java code,using the same connection string ,only different between my test is PreparedStatement and DriverManager .Both java code are connectiong to "A database".
PreparedStatement failed.DriverManager successed.
Thanks for your reply.
Hope someone can give me recommend,I had searched many but did't give any ieda.